# *ngFor not updating after database response

Tags: angular

On click a call is made to the server, does some stuff and sends back a response. Button for the first time, there is a reply but the screen is not updated

Typescript/Angular Markup

```
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  username = '';
  items: any = [];
  constructor(
    ) {
      this.items = [];
    }


ngOnInit() {

}
search(f: NgForm) {
  Meteor.call('search', f.value, (error, allResults) => {
    if (error) throw new Meteor.Error(error);
    this.items.push(allResults[0])
  }); 
}}
```

HTML Markup

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>搜尋</h2>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="search(f)" novalidate>
        <input name="first" ngModel required #first="ngModel">
        <input name="last" ngModel>
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>

      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">poj_unicode</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
            <td>{{item.poj_unicode}}</td>

          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table> 
</div>
```

Based on the above can anyone see where I'm going wrong with this as it's probably just some basic implementation I've missed.

Excuse me, does Angular have a setState similar to React? Thank

Comment: are you sure `allResults[0]` has any value with it or not?

Comment: Yes, because I’m testing, it works, thank you for your message

Comment: Excuse me, does Angular have a setState similar to React? Thank

Comment: You don't need a `setState` in Angular, it will update the HTML if a property of the component updates

Comment: Can you put a `console.log` before this line `this.items.push(allResults[0])` and check what is the response?

Comment: please console allResults[0] and after that put this.items = allResults[0]  also make js fiddle for this if its possible